# Adding sound to a MovieClip event in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Basically I have this sound effect that id like to add to my movie-clip. What happens is when I touch the ball (movie-clip) it moves to a new location, speeds up and the score climbs. At the exact point the ball is touched, id like the sound effect to play.

Here is the code for my **ball touch:)**

```
    function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void {
_touch = true;
timmyTimer.reset();
score +=1;
mcBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageWidth - mcBall.width));
mcBall.y = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageHeight - mcBall.height));
mcBall.nextFrame();
removeChild(mcBall);
timmyTimer.reset();
timmyTimer.start();
updateScores();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your sounds imported?

Then you can.

```
1. Export sound for action script.
2. After you have exported your sound. You can now create instance of your sound

var sound:Sound = new MySound();

3. Play Sound.

sound.play(1, 1); //(starttime, timesrepeat);
```